# MySQL: Use value from table 2 instead of table 1 when exists in table 2

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a transport planner written in PHP and MySQL,
To get the task rules per day, I use the following query:

```
SELECT  planning.*,     
        planning_dagen.planning_id, 
        planning_dagen.dagen,
        planning_dagen.data_import,
        routenummer_wijzigingen.routenummer AS temp_routenummer
FROM planning 
LEFT JOIN planning_dagen
USING (planning_id)
LEFT JOIN routenummer_wijzigingen
USING (planning_id)
WHERE :datum >= planning.datum
AND :datum <= geldig_tot
AND (frequentie = 'dagelijks' AND dayofweek(:datum) = planning_dagen.dagen
OR (frequentie = 'eenmalig' AND date(:datum) = planning.datum)
OR (frequentie = 'wekelijks' AND 0 = (abs(datediff(:datum, planning.datum)) % 7))
OR (frequentie = 'twee-wekelijks' AND 0 = (abs(datediff(:datum, planning.datum)) % 14))
OR (frequentie = 'maandelijks'
AND ceil(dayofmonth(:datum)/7) = ceil(dayofmonth(planning.datum)/7)
AND dayofweek(:datum) = dayofweek(planning.datum)))
AND dayofweek(:datum) <> '1'
AND dayofweek(:datum) <> '7'
```

In the `planning` table there is a column called `routenummer` (routenumber) which is used in most conditions (standard routenumber).
But as you can see I have also a `routenummer_wijzigingen` table which is used to give a task a different routenumber for certain day.

For example I have a task which returns every tuesday and wednesday and has routenumber 10. But on tuesday `2015-02-03` I need this task done by routenumber 9.
So I insert a rule in the `routenummer_wijzigingen` table which has the following columns:

```
routenummer_wijzigingen_id
planning_id
routenummer
datum
```

So when a date is selected and that date and planning_id exists in the `routenummer_wijzigingen` table, it has to take the routenumber from the `routenummer_wijzigingen` table instead of the `planning` table.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify join condition with `routenummer_wijzigingen` table (including `datum`). Then you should use `CASE` in your `SELECT` clause to decide which `routenummer` to choose.

```
SELECT  planning.*,     
    planning_dagen.planning_id, 
    planning_dagen.dagen,
    planning_dagen.data_import,
    CASE
        WHEN routenummer_wijzigingen.routenummer is not NULL
            THEN routenummer_wijzigingen.routenummer
        ELSE planning.routenummer
    END AS temp_routenummer
FROM planning
...
LEFT JOIN routenummer_wijzigingen rw on 
    planning.planning_id=rw.planning_id and rw.datum=...
```

Comment: Can you push me a little in the right direction about the WHERE clause..?

Comment: @JK87 No need to change anything in `WHERE` clause. Only in `SELECT` clause. I mistook keywords in my description.  It is corrected now.

Comment: in the case statement shouldn't it be `WHEN routenummer_wijzigingen.routenummer IS NOT NULL` instead of `<>`?